# Displaying messages from multiple notifications -Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase to send notifications to my App, when I receive the notification I store the message in my shared preferences and then display the message in an activity. However, as of right now I am only saving the latest notification message in the shared preferences. How do I save all the messages from the notifications in the shared preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you have some unique id for the message you are receiving from firebase. Now when you save the message in the shared preference use that unique id from the payload as the key. In your case, the MESSAGE_KEY is the same that's why it gets overwritten with the latest one. Just make the MESSAGE_KEY unique in the **saveKeyMessage** function and new shared preference instance will be created for each notification you receive.
 OR 
 You can use the following code to set the key as the unique key for you shared preference generation.

```
public boolean saveKeyMessage(String message){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
  mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Current Timestamp: " + format);
  editor.putString(unique_message_id, message);
  editor.apply();
  return true;

}
```

You can use the following code to display all shared preference instances

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
  mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> allPrefs = prefs.getAll(); //your sharedPreference
Set<String> set = allPrefs.keySet();
for(String s : set){
    LOG.d(TAG, s + "<" + allPrefs.get(s).getClass().getSimpleName() +"> =  "
            + allPrefs.get(s).toString());
```

Hope this solves you problem! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this helped me a lot, I have identified the issue, they all had the same id. However, how do I call that specific id on the getkeymessage() function?

Comment: You can create a new JSON object out of the payload ...   get the string out of it and pass it to the function. Use the same id to retrieve the shared preference. Please mark the answer as accepted, if this solved the problem as that would be helpful for anyone who faces this problem in the future.

Comment: I just did, pretty helpful. Do you mind adding how would this process look for the getkeymessage() function?

Comment: You will have to keep the all ids in some array or something and when you want to display it, just loop through all the ids and call the getKeyMessage function on each id and the id as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashSet` to store `messages` into `SharedPreferences`.

**#.** Store `messages` into `SharedPreferences`:

```
public static final String KEY_MESSAGES = "messages";

............
.................
public boolean saveKeyMessage(String message) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Get existing messages
    Set<String> messages = getMessages();

    // Add new message to existing messages
    messages.add(message);

    // Store messages to SharedPreferences
    editor.putStringSet(KEY_MESSAGES, messages);
    editor.apply();

    return true;
}
```

**#.** Get `messages` from `SharedPreferences`:

```
public Set<String> getMessages() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Get messages
    Set<String> messages = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY_MESSAGES, new HashSet<String>());

    return messages;
}
```

**#.** Get last `message` from `SharedPreferences`:

```
public String getLastKeyMessage() {

    ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>(getMessages());
    return messageList.get(messageList.size() - 1);
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you for your response, this would work if I was not using a version that does not support putStringSet()